# Split a string in Ant

Tags: ant

I need to split and manipulate a string using Ant.

Requirement is: I have following properties in my ant file

1. UserName=userName
2. Password=password
3. ConnectString=jdbc.oracle:thin@testdb:1521:db11g

I need to manipulate ConnectString to: 
jdbc.oracle:thin:userName/password@testdb:1521:db11g

Any pointers will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not built your ConnectString property like that ? :

```
 <property name="UserName" value="userName"/>
 <property name="Password" value="password"/>
 <property name="ConnectString" value="jdbc.oracle:thin:${UserName}/${Password}@testdb:1521:db11g"/>
```

Otherwise use script task with builtin javascript engine (JDK >= 1.6.0_06) and ant api for property manipulation, f.e. :

```
<project>
 <property name="UserName" value="userName"/>
 <property name="Password" value="password"/>
 <property name="ConnectString" value="jdbc.oracle:thin@testdb:1521:db11g"/>

 <script language="javascript">
  a = project.getProperty('ConnectString').split('@')

  // to overwrite existing ConnectString property use
  // project.setProperty('ConnectString' ...);
  project.setProperty('foo', a[0] + ':' + project.getProperty('UserName') +
   '/' + project.getProperty('Password') + '@' + a[1]);
 </script>

 <echo>$${foo} => ${foo}</echo>
</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] ${foo} => jdbc.oracle:thin:userName/password@testdb:1521:db11g
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rebse. In fact the user will be entering all the 3 string in that format, hence need to change it dynamically